Are convergent sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ neccesarily closed sets?
I believe it should be. Let $\{x_n \}$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Consider an element $y$ in the complement of it, we must show there is a ball with this element as the center such that the ball is still entirely in the complement. I think of defining the radius of this ball as:
$$ r = \text{inf}_n \{ |y- x_n | \big| x_n \in \{ x_n \}   \} $$
The infinimum exist as the $|y-x_n|>0$. We also note that $|y-x_n|$ can never be zero. Now, I need to show somehow that the infimum must be strictly above zero... but I can't figure out how.
Maybe this approach fails.. if so, how do I fix it and find an expression for the radius?

At the very least this statement should be some times true. If we have a constant sequence, then of course the elements of sequence form a closed set. If the answer for the question is negative, what more hypotheses are required on the statement for it? Thanks.

No. Counter-example: the set S:= ${ 1/n: n\in\mathbb{N} }.\ $ This is not closed because it has a limit point, namely $0,$ which is not in $S.$

If the sequence never reaches its limit, it will not be a closed set.

Just because all the elements are positive, it doesn't mean that the infimum is positive as well. And actually, this is not true in general. Because if you take $y$ to be the limit of the sequence then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (actually, this holds for all but finitely many $n$) such that $|y-x_n|<\epsilon$. Hence, there doesn't exist any ball around $y$ which doesn't intersect the set $\{x_n\}$.
So the correct statement is that if the sequence $x_n$ converges to $y$ then the set $\{x_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{y\}$ is closed. You have to add the limit in order to get a closed set. For example, $\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is closed. Try to prove the statement, it's a good exercise. Also, you can try to think how to generalize this to arbitrary sequences, not necessary convergent ones.

Counter example to the claim by infimum please

@CantorDustDrachen The infimum of the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ is $0$.

Consider the sequence $(\frac 1n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and the point $0 \in \mathbb R$, which is not in the sequence. The $r$ you have constructed above will end up being zero, which can be shown by contradiction:
If $r > 0$, pick $n \in \mathbb R$ such that $\frac 1 n < r$, then $ |0 - \frac 1 n| < r$, which is a contradiction. It is true however, that if we add the point of convergence $x \in \mathbb R$ to the convergent sequence, that said set is closed (in topology, this is called taking the closure of the set of the sequence).
Here your approach works in the following way: Let $\{x_n\}$ be a convergent sequence converging to $x$.
Let $y \in \mathbb R \setminus (\{x_n: n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{x\})$, i.e. let $y$ be in the complement. Let $\varepsilon = |x - y|$, and (by convergence of $x_n$) pick $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $n \ge N \Rightarrow |x - x_n| < \frac \varepsilon 2$.
This also implies that if $n \ge N: \varepsilon = |x - y| = |x - x_n + x_n - y| \le |x - x_n| + |y - x_n| \le \frac \varepsilon 2 + |y - x_n|$, hence for any $n \ge N$, we have that $|y-x_n| \ge \frac \varepsilon 2$. The idea is now that there can only be finitely many (at most $N-1$) points in $\{x_n\}$ such that $|y - x_n| < \frac \varepsilon 2$, hence you can take the minimum (not infimum) and get a number strictly greater than 0.
